# Scraping thousand of urls

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have a function that scrape a list of urls, 200k urls, it took a lot of time, there is a way to speed up this process?

```
def get_odds(ids):
  headers = {"Referer": "https://www.betexplorer.com",
                    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36'}
  s = requests.Session()
  matches=[]
  for id in ids:
    url = f'https://www.betexplorer.com{id}'
    response = s.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')
    season = url.split('/')[5]

    "do stuff.."
```

ids is a `list`

```
['/soccer/england/premier-league/brentford-norwich/vyLXXRcE/'
...]
```

Comment: The first step is to measure what takes the most time using a profiler.

Comment: it takes 1-2 seconds per urls but multiplied by 200k is a lot of time..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use multiprocessing.

Something like:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

if __name__ == "__main__":
    threads = 10 # The number of concurrent requests
    p = Pool(threads)
    p.map(get_odds, ids)
    p.terminate()
```

Where ids is the list of ids, and get_odds is the function you supplied, but modified to operate on JUST ONE of the ids. Keep in mind that you will be hitting their server with 10 requests at a time, and this can lead to temporary ip blocking (as you are seen as hostile). You should be mindful of that and adjust the pool size and or add sleep() logic.

The get odds function should be like:

```
def get_odds(id):
  headers = {"Referer": "https://www.betexplorer.com",
                    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36'}
  s = requests.Session()
  matches=[]
  url = f'https://www.betexplorer.com{id}'
  response = s.get(url, headers=headers)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')
  season = url.split('/')[5]

  "do stuff.."
```

Comment: Hm, the problem seems i/o-bound, so you better use `threading` or `asyncio`?

Comment: it seems that does not work I got `season = url.split('/')[5] IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: @Timus Multiprocessing has a higher memory footprint than threading, but in my experience leads to far more readable code and therefore fewer bugs than Threading. For web scraping, I have found that you encounter rate limits far sooner than memory issues. I have no experience with asyncio and so can't comment.

Comment: @luka That is an issue with your get_odds function, not the code I provided. After your id gets formatted into the url, it has fewer than 6 forward slashes in it, so you get an index error. Can you share what your ids looks like?

Comment: @PeterWhite '/soccer/england/premier-league/brentford-norwich/vyLXXRcE/' this is what looks like an id of ids list. When I run the script without multithreading I have no errors.

Comment: @luca did you alter your function so that it takes one id rather than a list of ids? I expect that your "for id in ..." is still there and it's iterating over the characters in the id. I updated my answer with an example.

Comment: @PeterWhite I modified the function in `get_odd(id)` and `  for id in ids:
    p = Pool(10)
    p.map(get_odds, id)
    p.terminate()` but same error

Comment: @luka you put the pool code in a for loop? You don't want to do that. The map function is the thing which is iterating over the ids. You should get rid of the for loop, and it should be p.map(get_odds, ids) plural  
If your get_odds function and your main function are both structured exactly as I put them in my answer post, it should work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239290/discussion-between-luka-and-peter-white).

Answer (score 0):

You could let them run in parallel via Multithreading. E.g. creating 10 threads and based on the ending of your id (0, 1, 2, 3, ...) knows the thread which ID it should scrape.
Does only work with enough computing power and stable internet connection.

EDIT: Since ID is a list, check the index instead to identify which thread should scrape which website.